# Is VueJS guaranteed to call mounted() in correct order?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

Let's say I have a basic page with VueJS as follows:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<p>Placed at index {{index}}</p>',
  data() {
    return {
      index: 0
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.index = this.$parent.addElement(this);
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#theParent',
  data() {
    return {
      allElements: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addElement(elem) {
      this.allElements.push(elem);
      return this.allElements.length - 1;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/2.3.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="theParent">
    <child></child>
    <child></child>
    <child></child>
</div>
```

The purpose of the output is just to illustrate at what index the elements have been inserted at. My use case requires that the elements are added in the same order that they appear in the HTML. Every time I run this page it appears that this is indeed happening as the output is in order.

My question is: Is this behavior guaranteed to always happen - will VueJS always execute `mounted()` on components in the order they appear in the HTML? If not, is there an alternate way to guarantee that they are added to my array in the proper order?

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your component the order is not guaranteed.

Why do you run `$parent.addElement`? Your component is already a child of this component. 

What you want to do is match the element order with a specific execution or der of functions, right? I suggest using a different source of truth like the array you are iterating through to create your child components rather than render order.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't feasible to create the `<child>` components from an array as they will be defined in my actual use case with a significant amount of HTML within them (rendered through `<slot></slot>`) and putting all that HTML into a string in an array would be a real mess.

Comment: Can you provide a code example that's closer to your actual use case?

Comment: Why use `mounted`? It depends on compiling template. I bet using `created` or even `beforeCreated` would do the trick. Check out the lifecycle here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Answer (score 0):

from my experience with Vue and Ag-Grid extension, it's not always the case.

To make sure it's loaded in the correct order, I implement `watch` function to let Vue know the DOM is ready.

even with `beforeMount` or `created` wont't help if the DOM element is somehow late-triggered.

```
  computed: {
    elementWatcher () {
      return this.whateverDOMElement // after this child is ready
    }
  }

  watch: {
    elementWatcher (val) {
      if (val) {
        this.mountAnother() // parent can be mounted
      }
    }
  }
```